# C# Static Dictionary Declare and Initialize in Abstract Class .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, dictionary, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and would like to add a static dictionary for error codes. I tried the following:

```
public abstract class Base
{
   ...
   protected static readonly Dictionary<int, string> errorDescriptions = new Dictionary<int, string>()
   {
      { 1, "Description1"},
      { 2, "Description2"},
      ...
    };
   ...
}
```

but then discovered that this was implemented in .NET 3.0; I am using 2.0. I looked around and some others suggested I add the pairs in the constructor but this is an abstract class.

How can/should I populate the dictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public abstract class Base
{
   ...
   protected static readonly Dictionary<int, string> errorDescriptions;
   // Type constructor called when Type is first accessed.
   // This is called before any Static members are called or instances are constructed.
   static Base ()
   {
      errorDescriptions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
      errorDescriptions[1] = "Description1";
      errorDescriptions[2] = "Description2";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just a few follow up questions. So if a derived class `DerivedClass` uses the dictionary `DerivedClass.errorSescriptions` the program first calls `Base()`? Or is it only used when a derived class is created, `public DerivedClass(,,) : base() {...}`? Is there a reason the constructor is static?

Comment: A single Dictionary is created and is available to all the subclasses.  Yes, it is instantiated before any of the subclasses are used.

Comment: If `Base` has other non-static fields, the constructor shouldn't be static correct?

Comment: @Jon You can have a static ctor and multiple instance ctor's in the same class.

Comment: errorDescriptions[1] = "Description1"; gives an error
you should use errorDescriptions.Add(1, "Description1");